# Can I use pytesseract in a WebApp?

Tags: python, django, python-tesseract

I am developing a WebApp with Django that allows users to upload an image, and "read" the text present in the image.I am using pytesseract to do this task. Everything worked well on my local machine, however when deploying this app on Linode (Ubuntu 18.04 LTS server) I keep getting an [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CY0Tm.png). I am curious if this is due to my code, or due to the nature of linode/pytesseract. I have read online that some hosting companies have anti-virus software that could hinder the use of such packages. Does anyone have advice or any insight on this topic? I am fairly new to web dev. so any advice will help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file you are trying to execute ends in .exe, which indicates that you are trying to run a Windows program, but your server runs Linux.

You should be able to run pytessaract, but you will have to use a Linux version of pytessaract.

Comment: Oh wow I can't believe I missed something that obvious. I was so focused on the inner workings of Linode that I overlooked that. I will give it a shot!

Comment: Followed your suggestion, and it works perfectly! I will make sure to be more thorough when attempting to solve a problem. Thanks a ton Daniel Hepper!!!

Comment: No worries, dependency management in Python is notoriously confusing, especially once you use platform-dependent libraries like pytessaract.